# Reload application data when the android app comes into foreground..?

Tags: android

Here is the scene what i am facing..when i press home key it saves the current state of the current activity..so when my app comes in foreground, onResume() of that particular activity gets called who's state was saved. So if an app with say 10 activities are there then, we will need to write reload of app data in each activity's onResume()..is there a way to specify a reload of app data in one activity only..?

Answer (score 1):

Jitesh,

Yes, this is possible.  You will probably want to perform the reloading of application data in your Activity's onResume() function.  See [Android Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Comment: even if user has pressed back key or home key..will onResume() work.

Comment: onResume() is called every time activity comes visible to user.

Comment: @vladimir @fresh  
Here is the scene what i am facing..when i press home key it saves the current state of the current activity..so when my app comes in foreground, onResume() of that particular activity gets called who's state was saved. So if an app with say 10 activities are there then, we will need to write reload of app data in each activity's onResume()..is there a way to specify a reload of app data in one activity only..?